# Switching to other screen through clicking an item of an MDList

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm looking to change my screen when I click on an MDList item. I want also to pass the information of the item into the new screen.

This is my code so far:

main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, ThreeLineListItem, ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem
from kasa import Discover
from decimal import Decimal
import asyncio
from pathlib import Path


class Device(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Device(name='screen1'))

class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('app.kv')

    def on_start(self):
        devices = asyncio.run(Discover.discover())
        for addr, dev in devices.items():
            asyncio.run(dev.update())
            self.root.ids.devices.add_widget(
            ThreeLineAvatarIconListItem(text=dev.alias,
             secondary_text="Current Power: %.2f" % Decimal(dev.emeter_realtime['power_mw'] / 10)  + " mW",
             tertiary_text="Current Runtime: " + dev.on_since.strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
             ))

 
            
Test().run()
```

app.kv

```
    #: import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

<Manager>:
    id: sm
    Device:
        id: device_screen
<Device>:
    name: 'screen1'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Test'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen 2'
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
    MDToolbar:
        title: 'SaveSmart'
        md_bg_color: .2, .2, .2, 1
    MDBottomNavigation:
        panel_color: .2, .2, .2, 1

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'screen 4'
            text: 'Dashboard'
            GridLayout:
                id: readings
                col: 2

        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'screen 3'
            text: 'Devices'
            ScrollView:
                MDList:
                    id: devices


        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'screen 1'
            text: 'Predictions'
            ScrollView:
                MDList:
                    OneLineListItem:
                        text: "Predictions go here!"
                        on_release: app.root.current = 'screen1'


        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'screen 2'
            text: 'Recommendations'

            MDLabel:
                text: 'Recommendations'
                halign:'center'
```

I tried to use app.root.current but it does not work. The program compiles but whenever I click on "Predictions go here!" it does not take me to a new page.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, every coder has own style , own formation. But I suggest you to create your pages and identify'em like my code below.Because its more easy and organized.I hope it helps you to redesign your code. I just added button to create my own items. Because i don't know `asyncio`.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineAvatarIconListItem
class Page1(Screen):
    mdlistid = ObjectProperty()
    def create_new_item(self,*args):
        item = OneLineAvatarIconListItem(text='Item')
        item.bind(on_release=self.change_page)
        self.mdlistid.add_widget(item)
    def change_page(self,*args):
        self.manager.current = 'page2'
class Page2(Screen):
    pass
class SM(ScreenManager):
    pass
KV = '''
<SM>:
    Page1:
        name: 'page1'
    Page2:
        name: 'page2'
<Page1>:
    mdlistid:mdlistid
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            size_hint_y:.1
            text: 'Create an Item'
            on_release: root.create_new_item()
        MDList:
            size_hint_y:.9
            id: mdlistid
<Page2>:
    Button:
        text: 'Go Page 1'
        size_hint:None,None
        size: 250,250
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
        on_release: root.manager.current = 'page1'
'''

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(KV)
        return SM()
MainApp().run()
```